# javascript ints evaluating incorrectly

Tags: javascript, if-statement, int, long-integer, bigint

So I am writing a javascript application, and basically if one number is greater than another I want to swap their values:

```
if(price1 > price2)
{
  var temp = price1;
  price1 = price2;
  price2 = temp;
}
```

This works fine up until a certain point, but once the numbers starting getting larger, i.e.:

```
price1: 12345678
price2: 234556
```

Then the expression will evaluate to false and will do nothing. Does anyone know what the issue is? Thanks!

Comment: Please put up a sample page somewhere demonstrating the problem. Numbers of that size should have no trouble being compared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure these are being compared as numbers? For example, if you change the code to

```
if (+price1 > +price2) {
    var temp = price1;
    price1 = price2;
    price2 = temp;
}
```

does it work? If so `price1` and `price2` are strings and the prefix `+` converts them to numbers.

Comment: I'm sure you hit it- '1' sorts lower than '2', no matter what digits follow in the strings. (+1)

Comment: I bet this is it.  Because the code as posted in the question indeed works fine, but fails when they are strings: http://jsfiddle.net/Squeegy/rwchF/1/

Answer (score 1):

Are you shure you are testing numbers?

As stated the values you specify are not so large to justify an error of that kind. It seems to me that the values are tested in lexicographic (as strings) order.

I would change your code accordingly

```
if(Number(price1) > Number(price2)) {
    var temp = price1;
    price1 = price2;
    price2 = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming both `price1` & `price2` are `ints`.

That to be correct [they should have](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5) a precision of `+/- 9007199254740992`.